# hastype(z,radical) gives different result

Tags: maple

I am completely baffled by this.

I noticed when a proc deep inside one of my modules is reached, where the original call was generated from command line, it works correctly than when the same proc is reached when the call flow is originated from inside another proc which is called from the command line.

I found it comes down to this one line. In the debugger, I see this

```
 if hastype(z,radical) then
    ...
```

This gives false in the second case, and it gives true when called in the first case. It should give true in both cases.

In the debugger, I look at z, it says it has this value

```
        1/x*sqrt(x^2*u)
```

Now, in the debugger command, when I type

```
        hastype(z,radical)
```

It gives `false`.  But when I type the actual value of `u` into the command:

```
       hastype(1/x*sqrt(x^2*u),radical)
```

Now it gives `true`!

Everything is local to this proc:

```
dsolve_step:-dsolve_step_homog:-convert_to_homog := proc(f0, x, y, u)
local f, z, tmp;
   1   f := f0;
   2   f := subs(y = u*x,expand(f));
   3   for z in op(f) do
   4 !     if hastype(z,radical) then    ##<=======
   5           tmp := sqrt(collect(z^2,x));
   6           f := subs(z = tmp,f)
           end if
       end do;
   7   return simplify(f)
end proc
```

So I have no idea why  `hastype(z,radical)` gives false, and `hastype(1/x*sqrt(x^2*u),radical)` gives true, when `z` itself is `1/x*sqrt(x^2*u)`.

And this happens only when I call the module as in case 2 described above.

As you can see, everything is local. `z,f,tmp` are local.  Same call the the above
function is made from both cases. All the input is the same in both cases.

Here are screen shots from the actual debugging:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I check

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I check by type the actual z value shown

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems like scoping issue, which I can't figure what it is. May be what I am looking at, is not what it appears to be.

Again, the same call works OK when I call the module from the command line, from another worksheet.

Both worksheets (case 1 and case 2), use different math engines. (I set up Maple to start new math engine for each work sheet to be safe)

I am looking for any suggestion why this happens.  The calling proc in the second case, does not use any global variables either. I always start from clean kernel (restart).

Any hint what is going on and what to look for? Or what to try to find what is the problem?

Maple 2018.1, windows 10.

---

**Update**

I found the problem. But I really think this is a bug in Maple.

I found if I use `eval(z)` then it works in the second case, like this:

```
 if hastype(eval(z),radical) then
```

Now I get true:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not see why I need to add `eval()` there, since Maple should automatically evaluate `z` to its value when using `for z in op(f) do` and then reference `z` inside the loop.

So my question has changed to: **Why is `eval()` needed here?**

Any way, I have a workaround for this. But this makes no sense to me now.

```
convert_to_homog:=proc(f0,x,y,u)
  local f,z,tmp;
  f:=f0;
  f:=subs(y=u*x,expand(f));

  #this below can give wrong answer sometimes. It tries to 
  #change 1/X*sqrt(x^2) to  sqrt(1)
  #by moving x under the sqrt. But this is valid only when x>0
  # i..e   1/x => sqrt(1/x^2)  only when x>0
  #keep it for now, until I implement exact solver.

  for z in op(f) do
      if hastype(eval(z), radical)  then
         tmp:=sqrt(collect(z^2,x));
         f:=subs(z=tmp,f);
      fi;
  od;
  return(simplify(f));

end proc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of key importance here is that (as shown by you), the value of `z` is involves an unevaluated call to `sqrt` and *not* something to power `1/2`.

The unevaluated `sqrt` call is not of type `radical`, though *what it evaluates to* is of that type.

First, let's deal with such an unevaluated call to `sqrt` at the top-level (ie. not inside any procedure body). We first assign to name `z` the expression containing the unevalated call to `sqrt`.

We'll test the type of 1-level evaluation of name `z`, as well as the full evaluation of the name `z`.

```
restart;
z := '1/x*sqrt(x^2*u)';

                           2
                     sqrt(x  u)
                z := ----------
                         x
```

1-level evaluation of `z` produces its value, but with no other evaluation. The `sqrt` call remains unevaluated.

```
eval(z, 1); # 1-level evaluation

                         2
                   sqrt(x  u)
                   ----------
                       x
```

The unevaluated call to `sqrt` is *not* of `type` `radical`.

```
hastype(eval(z, 1), radical);

                     false
```

Now here is the full evaluation of `z`, which is default behavior at the top-level.

```
eval(z); # full evaluation      

                     2   1/2
                   (x  u)
                   ---------
                       x

z;

                         2   1/2
                   (x  u)
                   ---------
                       x
```

Passing `z` to `hastype` now passes the full evaluation to `hastype`.  That is, the expression passed to `hastype` now contains something to power `1/2`, and it recognized as being of `type` `radical`.

```
hastype(z, radical);         

                     true
```

Now read this, from a [bullet point](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=procedure#evalrules) in the section "Evaluation Rules" on the help-page for TOPIC `proc`,

```
"Within a procedure, during the execution of its
 statementSequence, local variables have single level
 evaluation. This means that using a variable in an
 expression will yield the current value of that variable,
 rather than first evaluating that value."
```

Let's look at a similar example as above, but within a procedure.

First, we'll deal with `z` in the procedure. As earlier, the name `z` is assigned the expression containing the unevaluated `sqrt` call. In contrast to the top-level behavior, within the procedure the assigned local `z` is evaluated only 1-level.

```
restart;

f := proc( f0 )       
  local z;
  lprint( f0 );
  z := f0;
  lprint( z );
  hastype(z, radical);
end proc:

f( '1/x*sqrt(u*x^2)' );

1/x*sqrt(u*x^2)
1/x*sqrt(u*x^2)
                     false
```

And now we'll alter the procedure to deal with `eval(z)`, which gets the expression containing something to power `1/2`.

```
restart;              

f := proc( f0 )        
  local z;             
  lprint( f0 );        
  z := f0;             
  lprint( eval(z) );   
  hastype(eval(z), radical);
end proc:                   

f( '1/x*sqrt(u*x^2)' );     

1/x*sqrt(u*x^2)
1/x*(u*x^2)^(1/2)
                     true
```

So it appears that you are experiencing the documented and intended behavior for evaluation of assigned local variables within a procedure. That is not a bug.

You have only supplied a fragment of the code, and have not shown exactly what are the arguments `f0, x, y, u` passed to procedure `convert_to_homog`.  But you *have* shown that local `z` is `1/x*sqrt(x^2*u)` and *not* `1/x*(x^2*u)^(1/2)` and if that is true then it is not a bug that `hastype(z,radical)` returns `false`.

With you current set up, yes, you can pass `eval(z)` to `hastype` and get the `true` result you expect.

But perhaps you should also re-examine why `z` is being assigned the unevaluated expression in the first place. Is that deliberate, or because of accidental programming earlier?

Comment: Thanks. This is all new to me that local variables in a proc do not fully evaluate when referenced. This makes it really hard to program in Maple if one has to do eval(var) around each local variable to insure that it fully evaluated. The code will also now look ugly as I have to wrap each variable with eval() around it. This for me makes no sense why Maple does this for local variables in  a proc.  I expected when I reference a variable, then it full evaluated value is what is used....

Comment: `But perhaps you should also re-examine why z is being assigned the unevaluated expression in the first place` Well, as you can see in the code. I passed in `f0` to the proc, which a local variable `f` is assigned to it so I can change it. Then used `f` later in the loop. So the `sqrt` was in the the `f0` expression coming down the call chain.  It is hard to post full code example showing all the calls, since it is too long. But now I understand the difference between local variables evaluation. I have to think more about this. This for me makes Maple programming very tricky.

Comment: Your central issue here seems to be that you are preventing evaluation of `f0` as passed into the proc, somewhere earlier. You could figure out where that happens, and why. It doesn't necessarily make sense to blame Maple's evaluation model on (even unintentionally) wrong earlier code. Perhaps it's due to a `parse` without any `eval`. Or (partially) compounded by using `subs` or `subsindets` when `eval` or `evalindets` would serve better. We cannot see all your code.

Comment: I can try to make a MWE. The orginal expressions `f0` in this case, are Maple expressions. They are read from plain text file as strings. I read each expression from the file as string, uses `parse` on them to convert them to an actual maple expression so I can use them, then pass them to the above proc for processing. so `sqrt()` was how the original Maple expression/string was in the file as read.  I will change my code to apply `eval` to the result of `parse` when I first read the file and see if this changes things and resolve this problem. Thanks.